# Schedule query in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql, scheduled-tasks, sql-server-2014

I am trying to schedule a SQL query in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

For some reason I am unable to find SQL Server Agent (i.e. to expand Jobs to create Schedule).

Is there a new way to schedule SQL query on SQL Server 2014?

Thanks

Comment: Which **edition** of SQL Server are you running? Check by running `SELECT @@VERSION` - the **Express** edition for example doesn't have SQL Server Agent jobs

Comment: Is it installed? Is the service running?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Windows Task Scheduler** to run your SQL query.
Follow below link to creation and deployment of task.

[Click here to create windows task](http://www.prairiefyre.com/kb/Print51069.aspx)

Comment: I shall try this

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Express does not include SQL Server Agent.  Editions higher than that (such as Standard, Enterprise/Developer) do.

If your edition supports SQL Server Agent, make sure it is installed.

If it is installed, you may need to configure it before you see it show up as available in SSMS.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE  
GO
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/agent-xps-server-configuration-option)

This is for the most basic configuration, without regard to permissions and such.  For that, it's probably worth reading [this short overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-sql-server-agent).

Comment: I shall try this